# See the invite code used by a person who joins with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I would like to know if there's any way to have a bot log the invite code that a user uses to join my server. For example when a person joins, it would look something like this:

```
-User@1234 joined the server using the code "XXXXXXXX" which was created by User@4321
```

Comment: Easiest way, without coding anything at all would be to use an [invite tracker](https://github.com/cyrus01337/invites)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to check for increments in the number of uses of all the invites when a new member joins. Then the inviter can be checked of the invite that incremented. I don't know the channel in which your users are joining so here's a general approach(from [here](https://medium.com/@tonite/finding-the-invite-code-a-user-used-to-join-your-discord-server-using-discord-py-5e3734b8f21f)):

```
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="&")
invites = {}
@bot.event
async def on_ready(): 
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        invites[guild.id] = await guild.invites()
def find_invite_by_code(invite_list, code):
    for inv in invite_list:     
        if inv.code == code:      
            return inv
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):

    invites_before_join = invites[member.guild.id]
    invites_after_join = await member.guild.invites()

    for invite in invites_before_join: 
        if invite.uses < find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses:

            print(f"Member {member.name} Joined")
            print(f"Invite Code: {invite.code}")
            print(f"Inviter: {invite.inviter}")

            invites[member.guild.id] = invites_after_join

            return
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):

    invites[member.guild.id] = await member.guild.invites()
bot.run("YOUR TOKEN HERE")
```

Comment: Note that this will only work reliably if you have members joining the server with a small enough interval, say once per minute or fewer. Otherwise there may be race conditions where more than one member joined and we cannot discern which invite they used.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. I'll give them each a try right now.

Comment: Just to update, Nazar Khan and Łukasz Kwieciński, both your methods worked. Thank you very much my issue of over 3 days has now been solved :D