# I'm trying to give role to a member after inviting 2 members to the server or have 2 or more invite uses, I'm uncertain if I used the correct event

Tags: discord, discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready(member):
    if member.invites.uses == 2:
        Premium = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Premium")
        await client.add_roles(member, Premium)
```

I haven't had any errors and yes, intents are enabled

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498590/see-the-invite-code-used-by-a-person-who-joins-with-discord-py) could be helpful, you would just need to add the functionality above (not in `on_ready`, but rather in `on_member_join`). You can read more about events [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference)

Comment: You should not add random tags to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`on_ready()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_ready) will only execute on bot startup. What you want is probably [`on_member_join(member)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_join).
2. You can't get the invite by doing `member.invite`, as [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member) objects does not provide it.
3. [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) takes a list of roles, not a single role.

[A solution to your problem](https://medium.com/@tonite/finding-the-invite-code-a-user-used-to-join-your-discord-server-using-discord-py-5e3734b8f21f) could be to register each invite in a dict, then compare each of them when a member joins.